# In wordpress, how to show previous and next category name?

Tags: wordpress, categories

Let say there are category 1, category 2, category 3...etc. 
And I am on a post page of category 2. I want to show previous and next category name on the content area which will be 'category 1' and 'category 3'.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Able to figure it out.

```
<?php
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $separator = ' ';
            $output = '';
            if($categories){
                foreach($categories as $category) {
                    $prev_step .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id-1 ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '" class="previous-step">'.get_cat_name( $category->term_id-1 ).'</a>'.$separator;
                    $next_step .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id+1 ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '" class="next-step">'.get_cat_name( $category->term_id+1 ).'</a>'.$separator;
                }
            }
            ?>
        <?php echo trim($prev_step, $separator);?>
        <?php echo trim($next_step, $separator);?>
```